# CarouselView is Empty in Modal Page

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

i used carousel View inside Page when that Page Appear as Modal Page Carousel View is Empty
When i Save the xaml Page Carousel View Will Appear
this is my Carousel View

```
<CarouselView IsBounceEnabled="True"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
                          PeekAreaInsets="50"
                          HeightRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=180,Tablet=200,TV=250,Watch=150}"
                          Grid.Row="5"
                          IsVisible="{Binding ImagesAreNull,Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter}}">
                <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                    <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                       ItemSpacing="20"
                                       SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle"
                                       SnapPointsAlignment="Center"/>
                </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Aspect="Fill"
                               Source="{Binding .}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CurrentItem" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PreviousItem">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                                    Value="0.5" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NextItem">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                                    Value="0.5" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="DefaultItem">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                                    Value="0.25" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>
```

i binded item source to a view model and the source is not empty.
this is where i push this page as modal page

```
private void CardView_OnShowMore(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var product = (sender as CardView)?.ShowMoreCommandParameter as Product;
        Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ProductDetailPage(new Product()
        {
            Title = product.Title,
            Amount = product.Amount,
            Description = product.Description,
            ImageProfile = product.ImageProfile,
            Images = product.Images,
            Location = product.Location,
            RegistrationDate = product.RegistrationDate,
            _id = product._id
        }), true);
    }
```

sorry if my grammar is bad.

before and after save and reload xaml file:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAj12.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cGql.png)

Comment: Do you set the `BindingContext` to the product  in your `ProductDetailPage` ?You could show your ProductDetailPage codes.

Comment: Yes i did i binded it to a model and that model have string array for images

Comment: It seems to be all right.What do you mean "Save the xaml Page" ?

Comment: i mean hot reload. when i save the xaml design it will appear